# How to disable plain FTP with proftp and xinetd?

Tags: ftp, authentication, ftps, xinetd, proftpd

I'm using CentOS release 6.4 on a VPS.
Its runs proftp with xinetd

I've found configuration files at

/etc/proftpd.conf
/etc/xinetd.conf
/etc/xinetd.d/ftp_psa

I want to **disable** plain FTP, but need to keep **FTPS**.
So a ftp client tries to start a connection via plain FTP it shouldn't be allowed.

How to make this happen?

Comment: Don't tangle up sftp with ftps. Whole different routines.

Comment: Look at the answers.

Answer (score 2):

There is this parameter: [TLSRequired](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_TLSRequired.html) for `mod_tls` in Proftpd.

> Synopsis
>
> TLSRequired [ on | off | ctrl | data | auth | auth+data]

If you set it to `on` then all ftp users will be forced to use TLS for both control and data channels. There are other options available also to activate it only for control channel, that is for username/password transfer.

It should be added to the `mod_tls` config:

```
<IfModule mod_tls.c>
    ...
    TLSRequired on
    ...
    ...
</IfModule>
```

There are possible issues that when you enable tls for both channels some client software will fail to list directories after logins and hang. May be in such a case, it is good enough to active tls only for auth channel.

Please read the Q&A sections here for more info: http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/TLS.html.

Comment: This is exactly what the duplicate answer  says.

Comment: Hi @lain, I have read the other answer and wanted to give an answer to foucs only on the specific parameter `TLSRequired` and related issue, which I have found missing in the other answer.